# Satisfy two conditions with a single if in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++14, c++builder

Is there any way to simultaneously satisfy two conditions in C++?

I have a list of

```
 x and y
-1    -1
-1     0
-1     1
 0    -1
 0     0
 0     1
 1    -1
 1     0
 1     1
```

So I want to use all of them combination in a equation such as:

```
a = x+y (example)
```

however I want to exclude the situation in which x and y are = 0 simultaneously.

so I tried:

```
if(x!=0 && y!=0){
a = x+y;
}
```

But that excludes every case when x or y are equal to 0 and not just the point x,y = (0,0) as I want.

How can I solve that?

Comment: it can as simple as this `if(x or y)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need

```
if (!(x == 0 && y == 0)) {
    ...
}
```

You can use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to translate it to

```
if (x != 0 || y != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Finally!!  After years of teaching Computer Organization and Architecture I see somebody actually applying Boolean algebra to solve a design problem...Just the fact that you mention it makes me smile.  :)  Ahhhh those basic identities are still alive and well!!

Comment: One catch with your solution though...the case where x = -1 and y = 1.  Their sum is zero.  Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

You should Use logical **OR** operator instead of **AND** operator to get the expected result:

```
if(x!=0 || y!=0){
   a = x+y;
}
```

The boolean table of this condition will be `false` if only both operands are `0` other than it's `true`:

```
0  0  false
1  0  true 
0  1  true
1  1  true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a exnot condition with and condition

```
if (!(x == 0 && y == 0)) { //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace utility{
  bool all_of( std::initializer_list<bool> bs ){
    return std::all_of(bs.begin(), bs.end(), [](bool b){return b;});
  }
  bool any_of( std::initializer_list<bool> bs ){
    return std::any_of(bs.begin(), bs.end(), [](bool b){return b;});
  }
}
```

then

```
if(!utility::all_of({x==0, y==0})){
  a = x+y;
}
```

or

```
if(!(x==0 && y==0)){
  a = x+y;
}
```

if you are more sane.